# How to optimize parameters for HoughLinesP to avoid ghost line in a turn

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence, houghlinesp

I am currently working on a project of an automated car and I have an issue with HoughLinesP function. When the car is turnning, it detects a "ghost line". Bellow is the code of my function and these are the parameters:

edges: Output of the edge detector.

lines: A vector to store the coordinates of the start and end of the line.

rho: The resolution parameter \rho in pixels.

theta: The resolution of the parameter \theta in radians.

threshold: The minimum number of intersecting points to detect a line.

I increased the threshold parameter but it has a negative effect on the straight lines.

Any solution is welcome.

```
#Line segment detection
def detect_line_segments(cropped_edges):
    rho = 1  #Precision in pixel, i.e. 1 pixel
    angle = np.pi / 180  #Degree in radian, i.e. 1 degree
    min_threshold = 10  #Minimal of votes
line_segments = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped_edges, rho, angle, min_threshold, np.array([]),
                                minLineLength=5, maxLineGap=4)

return line_segments
```

[initial frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3G40.jpg)

[extracted edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj2CI.png)

[lane lines segements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W7IN.jpg)